# Function to delete columns needs to be run 6 times to work as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following macro.

```
Sub SeasonTeas()
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim ArrSize As Long
ArraySize = lastColumn - 1
Dim elem As Long
ReDim SelectColumns(ArraySize)
For x = 1 To (lastColumn)
    If Cells(1, x).Value <> "respid" And Cells(1, x).Value <> "status" And Cells(1, x).Value <> "CID" Then
        Columns(x).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

I need to find columns that do not match respid/status/CID and delete everything else.

It needs to run 6 times to do what I need.

I know there is probably a more efficient way but I would like to get it working this way before trying something else.

Comment: could you explain more? why do you have to run 6 times?

Comment: the file i'm using it on currently has 63 columns and will end with 3. it seems as though the macro will only delete half of the columns each time it's run. after running it six times i'm left with the columns i want

Comment: @markfitzgerald has the solution. traverse the columns in the opposite direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you need to run your macro up to six times to get the desired result is that as you delete a column, the remaining columns move to the left and the column that was immediately to the right of the deleted column is not tested on the next loop iteration.

For example, column 1 is deleted so column 2 becomes column 1 but on the next loop, x=2 so the new column 1 doesn't get tested.

```
Sub SeasonTeas2()
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim x As Long

'Define your last column
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Step backwards from your  last column
For x = lastColumn To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, x).Value <> "respid" And Cells(1, x).Value <> "status" And Cells(1, x).Value <> "CID" Then
        Columns(x).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Stepping through your code using F8 allows you to see what each command does as it is executed so you can see if your code is behaving as you expected.

Comment: Scanning right to left is the correct approach, so +1 for that.  But you have reproduced an error in the OP, all references to `Cells(1,x)` and `Columns(x)` refer to the active sheet, which may or may not be `Sheet1`

Comment: Fair comment. I should've changed '    lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column' to '    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column' but I was more focussed on what was happening in the loop.